# How to Animate Modal popup Dialog component opening and closing in nativescript-angular app?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am using modal dialog component in nativescript angular app I am trying to implement Animate modal popup dialog for opening slideup and closing slidedown 
but in android device it not working.
How can we give transition for modal popup for android device?

Comment: Slide down / up transition is not supported out of the box, but you should be able to write the native code for [transition](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_transition_.transition).

Comment: let options = {
      context: {},
      fullscreen: true,
      // fullscreen: false,
      animated: true,
      stretched: false,
      dimAmount: 0.5,
      transition: {
        name: "slideTop",
        duration: 500,
        curve: "easeIn"
      },
      viewContainerRef: this._vcRef
    };
    this._modalService.showModal(ModalComponent, options).then(res => {
     
    });           with this code not it taking transition property

Comment: My bad, you are right. Transition is not supported on modal but only in Frame navigation. You will need a custom dialog fragment (Android) to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Yesterday I posted a fix for android modal animations https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5989#issuecomment-521325207

I'm waiting to see if they'll go ahead with that PR to fix the broken android modal animations.

To do custom animations, you can find some online for slide_up/slide_down and put them in `res/anim` of the android project and then reference the name of a `style` for setting the window animations. You'll find more info on github comment.

Comment: Thanks for answer Brad Martin above  fix working fine